# Webdriver CSS Selector, nth-child position 1 higher than expected

Tags: webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

I've recently been making the switch over to using CSS Selectors over Xpath. I've come across something that I can't explain and I was hoping someone more knowledgeable can assist.

```html
<form id="configure_server">
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">...</div>
        <div class="form_input_elements">...</div>
    </div>
    <input name="serverID" id="serverID" value="2" type="hidden">
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">...</div>
        <div class="form_input_elements">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">...</div>
        <div class="form_input_elements">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">...</div>
        <div class="form_input_elements">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">Name</div>
        <div class="form_input_elements">Thor</div>
    </div>
    <input name="name" id="name" value="Thor" type="hidden">
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">...</div>
        <div class="form_input_elements">...</div>
    </div>
    <div class="form_row">
        <div class="form_label">...</div>
        <div class="form_input_elements">...</div>
    </div>
</form>
```

I'm attempting to get the text of the element that equals `Thor`.

To find that element and retrieve its text I am using:

```py
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#configure_server>div.form_row:nth-child(6)>div.form_input_elements")
```

I'm confused that I have to use `:nth-child(6)`, I expected to use `:nth-child(5)`. Can anyone explain why I'm having to reference the child one index higher?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's an `input` element after your first `div.form_row`, which makes that `input` the second child of your form. This shifts all the other elements forward by one index, making your fifth `div.form_row` the *sixth child* of your form, because all your `input`s and `div`s are siblings sharing the same parent form.

If all your elements in the form are either `div.form_row`s or hidden inputs, you can choose to use `div:nth-of-type(5)` instead of `div.form_row:nth-child(6)`:

```py
self.driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#configure_server>div:nth-of-type(5)>div.form_input_elements")
```

Note that the class name is not accounted for in `:nth-of-type()`; only the element type (its tag name). But if the only `div`s directly under your form are `div.form_row`, it doesn't matter whether you qualify it with the `.form_row` class.

Comment: Thanks for that. I assumed it was as such but I wasn't able to find anything that confirmed my suspicions so thought it best to ask. Thanks again.